# Replace multiple variable values in string using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string that looks like this:

```
1080p [2.1GB] 720p [1.3GB] 480p [500MB]
```

In Python, I want to replace all the `[x]` with `,`. I've tried this code:

```
import re
s1 = '1080p [2.1GB] 720p [1.3GB] 480p [500MB]'
s2 = re.sub("[(.*?)]", ", ", s1)
```

However, I get as this output: `1080p [2, 1GB] 720p [1, 3GB] 480p [500MB]`.

Instead, I would like to obtain something like `1080p, 720p, 480p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.split`.

```
>>> s1 = '1080p [2.1GB] 720p [1.3GB] 480p [500MB]'
>>> ', '.join(i for i in re.split(r'\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*', s1) if i)
'1080p, 720p, 480p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the brackets and use raw string:

```
s2 = re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]", ", ", s1)
```

Note that outside of character class, these symbols - `.^$*+?()[{\|` - should be escaped to match literally.

Here is [a demo](https://ideone.com/ljYiu7)

If you do not plan to use the contents inside `[...]`, remove the round brackets.

```
s2 = re.sub(r"\[.*?\]", ", ", s1)
```

To obtain a "cleaner" string, you may use a bit more sophisticated regex and `strip()`:

```
import re
s1 = '1080p [2.1GB] 720p [1.3GB] 480p [500MB]'
s2 = re.sub(r"\s*\[.*?\]", ",", s1)
print s2.strip(' ,')
```

Output of [another demo](https://ideone.com/bhwKSu): `1080p, 720p, 480p`

Comment: but this adds  a comma and space at the last.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I see, but *i would like something like 1080p, 720p, 480p* just means something similar, so it does answer the main issue why the regex was not working.

Comment: I added an improved solution.

Comment: What is `[]` present at the start.. you may shorten your regex as `re.sub(r"\s*\[.*?\]", ", ", s1).rstrip(', ')`

Comment: I think I already have it, just did not fix in the demo. I also fixed a typo in the answer just now. I also assume there are always spaces between `[]`s and other entities, otherwise, the replacement string should be as in the original.